# Users activity in the world infographic

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is there any report or statistics for StackOverflow showing from what places of the world most users come from at the time? In other words, I would like to see what parts of the world are "most active" during the 24 hour diurnal cycle.

Of course, one can say that during 9-16 CET most active will be Europe, then United States come into play etc. But still, such **infographic** could be quite interesting I believe.

If not, is there any way to prepare such infographic? I am not aware of any public API that allows to track data about currently logged users. Is there any?

Comment: The user's "seen" status is public. however you'd probably need to dedicate time and database space to save it. This would however be morerelevat if you are really looking of activity of "users" rather than visitors.

Comment: I think you could go and ask the API (if some exists) for the countries of users active in last 30 minutes. That should already produce some ammount of data that can be handled.

Answer (score 6):

Sure there are. These statistics and more are available at ***https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!traffic*** .

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: There's another interesting statistics on this site. Apparently 4% of users, "addicts", are making 51% of visits. It's a little disappointing to me if what we produce is mostly seen by other SO addicts and not so much by developers in need.

Comment: Alternatively- you could interpret the stats as the 96% is (new) users asking questions, optimistically one would assume are getting their questions answered by the 4% who are dedicating a lot of effort into doing so :)

Comment: I wonder why all the countries seem to peak/trough at the same time ? I would have thought that the peaks would be related to the time zone ?

Comment: @PaulR Thats days per week not hours per day. The hills are weekdays.

Comment: @PaulR: This doesn't show the daily 24h cycle but rather the weekly cycle. There is one data point per day. The highs are workdays and the lows weekends.

Comment: ... which is another way of saying, *this answer doesn't address the question!*

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: thanks - I was thrown off by the US date format - I see that it's weekly now.

Comment: Yes, this is nice but not answers the question - it is not suprising that during weekend the traffic is smaller. Still searching for the data then...

Comment: "Not surprising" that most traffic is during work hours? ((cough))

Comment: Although I do not see "work hours" statistic and I was talking about workdays - yes, it is not surprising for me. SO is not for "hobbyist", but for "developers", and they mostly develop during they work. And as they develop, they need to find&ask questions...